# Share file/folder without copy permission in Windows 7

Tags: windows, file-permissions, window, shared-folders

I have a shared folder in Windows 7 that a user can access with read permission.
The problem is that, the user can also copy the shared files.
I don't want them to do that.
I just want them to view the files without copy permission.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Go through this maybe it will help you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726004(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: it does not explain how to grant read access without copy files

Comment: Ok will find more solution and will provide you.. Wait till that. :)

Comment: It's not possible. Anything that can be read can be copied.

Comment: As Schneier colorfully puts it, trying to make bits uncopiable is like trying to make water not wet.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you cant since theres only **read**  and **read/write** permissions only, so to prevent the person from copying you would have to disable the reading permission reading

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)